# After Copying Ubuntu 21.04 to New Drive, Boots Only to Grub. Cannot boot to DVD Live Disk

Tags: boot, grub2

After copying Ubuntu 21.04 to a new drive (it is an Ubuntu-only system), I need to repair the boot but not sure how to do so. It boots to Grub, then goes to initramfs but it can go to the Grub command line by pressing c. Can it be repaired from the Grub command line? I see many other posts here and elsewhere about this very issue but nothing I tried seemed to work.

Trying to boot to the live DVD, it gives many errors (`Failed to start Snap Daemon` and `Failed to start Holds Snappy daemon refresh` among others) then eventually goes to a blank screen with only the cursor.

Comment: This answer explains how to update grub from a live usb. It sounds like in your case you don't need to do step 3. https://askubuntu.com/a/1065750/243321  If the partition UUIDs change, you will likely need to fix /etc/fstab as well.

Comment: As stated, I cannot boot to the live DVD. Just errors, then a blank screen with the cursor. I can boot to other installation media such as Haiku and Windows 10 but not Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, you said DVD, but I asked about USB.

Comment: Unfortunately the USB drives do not show up in my Windows image burning software (I’ve not found any Linux burning software that doesn’t make lots of duds) so I’ve not been able to try that. I tried for hours but nothing I did made them show up even though they were there and accessible in the file manager.

Comment: I’m beginning to think that there is some BIOS setting that works when booting to hard drive but not to anything else!

Comment: Ended up having to use yet another burning software made specifically for USB drive image burning, then after some adjustments in the BIOS, it now boots to the USB or DVD. Making the USB drive and DVD required Windows, though.